# Add fade-effect to mouseover jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm new to jQuery and trying out this code for swapping an image on mouseover.

```
$("#Mr1").on({
 "mouseover" : function() {
    this.src = 'design/images/11.png';
  },
  "mouseout" : function() {
    this.src='design/images/10.png';
  }
});
```

The code works perfectly fine, but I would like to add a fade effect when the images swap. I tried adding parts to the code in order to make this work but then the code always stops working. Could someone give me a hand?

Comment: can you show which code is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do it properly with one element only, cause you can overlap only one image at a time.

Solution: ***[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/AZeGIVoQ/1/edit)***

```
  <span class="fade">
    <img src="design/images/10.png">
    <img src="design/images/11.png">
  </span>
```

CSS:

```
.fade img{ position:absolute; }
```

jQ:

```
$('.fade').hover(function(){
  $('img:eq(1)', this).stop().fadeToggle(400);
});
```

Comment: fadeOut / change src / onload => fadeIn sounds doable with one element only. No crossfade possible, but still.

Comment: @Jon yes it's doable, but in the meantime (before the images changes) you'll get the white background (or whatever color) that in web-design it's not an option. The transition (talking about **fade**) between wto elements should be smooth.

Comment: Well, you could also preload the images. Anyway, this is just philosophical chatter.

Comment: @jon even if you preload your images you'll get the gap.